# How to create an Azure Image from a .vhd file using azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have a custom vhd which I have in my Azure VM. It's a linux machine. I need to use azure cli to create an Image from this vhd file. This image will then be used to create VMs which have a username and Password. I have successfully used the vhd to create an Image using the Portal and created a VM out of it. However, I am unable to create an image using cli commands. This is what I get when I run the command -

```
jenkins@Jenkins-vm:~/testFolder$ az image create -g myRG -n myImage --os-type Linux --source ./myCustom.vhd
usage: az image create [-h] [--verbose] [--debug] [--only-show-errors]
                       [--output {json,jsonc,yaml,yamlc,table,tsv,none}]
                       [--query JMESPATH] [--subscription _SUBSCRIPTION]
                       --resource-group RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --name NAME
                       --source SOURCE [--os-type {Windows,Linux}]
                       [--data-disk-sources DATA_DISK_SOURCES [DATA_DISK_SOURCES ...]]
                       [--location LOCATION]
                       [--storage-sku {Standard_LRS,Premium_LRS,StandardSSD_LRS,UltraSSD_LRS}]
                       [--hyper-v-generation {V1,V2}]
                       [--os-disk-caching {None,ReadOnly,ReadWrite}]
                       [--data-disk-caching {None,ReadOnly,ReadWrite}]
                       [--tags [TAGS [TAGS ...]]]
                       [--zone-resilient [{true,false}]]
az image create: error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'os_disk'
```

I don't understand the meaning of the error displayed.
I'm very new to Azure so feeling a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the description of the CLI command `az image create`:

> Create a custom Virtual Machine Image from managed disks or snapshots.

And the description of the parameter `--source`:

> OS disk source from the same region, including a virtual machine ID or
> name, OS disk blob URI, managed OS disk ID or name, or OS snapshot ID
> or name.

It means the CLI command only can create VM images from Azure, not matter the VM blob URI, managed disk, or snapshot, all of them should exist in Azure. So you need to upload the VHD file to Azure Storage Blob, and then use the VHD URI to create the VM image via the CLI command. And one thing you need to watch out is that the VHD file should be the OS disk.

Comment: ` az storage blob copy start --source-path ./myCustom.vhd --destination-blob myCustom.vhd --destination-container myBlob ` is giving error:
```
az storage blob copy start: error: Invalid usage: Neither a valid blob or file source is specified.
```
Please advise the correct syntax

Comment: @RameshMenon Please use the command [`az storage blob copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_copy) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Charles Xu. It is working. I'm very new to Azure - just 1 week.

Could you also please advise whether this is how I can create an Image from the vhd that is being saved to blob storage:
` az image create -g MyRG -n myImage1 --os-type Linux --source /subscriptions/aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/myBlob/myCustom.vhd `

Comment: @RameshMenon If it works for you please accept it as the answer. And as I said in the answer, the CLI command just works for Azure, not your local VHD file. See the description of the CLI command.

Comment: You are fantastic. Saved my day.
Both commands worked and now I am being able to create a VM using the Image that was made from my vhd file. Thank you very very much.