# Azure-CLI - Creating an NVA VM from a VHD in Container

Tags: azure-cli

i have a VHD for an NVA in a page blob container in my storage account. I'm unable to work out how to create the VM using Azure CLI because i'm struggling to understand the difference between managed disk, ephemeral-os-disk etc etc. Appreciate any guidance.

```
    $image="https://sdwan-nva.blob.core.windows.net/os21/cpe-image-577a81b21.vhd"
    $vmsize="Standard_F8s_v2"
    $tags="Engineer=ME"
    $Zone="1"

az vm create --name AZURE-NVA1 -g RG1 --accept-term --size $vmsize --tags $tags --zone 1 --admin-username cpeadmin --authentication-type ssh --generate-ssh-keys --accelerated-networking false --nic-delete-option Detach --nics SDWAN-CPE-1-IF1, SDWAN-CPE-1-IF2, SDWAN-CPE-1-IF3 --subnet SDWAN-SUBNET1
```

I tried the --source option as mentioned in this thread but it's not even available.

[How to create an Azure Image from a .vhd file using azure cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878693/how-to-create-an-azure-image-from-a-vhd-file-using-azure-cli)

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have VHD file upload in blob storage container like below:

[image]

To create VM from VHD in container, create a managed disk from a VHD file in a storage account using below script:

```
$subscriptionId= "7195d375-7af2-43f1-bd66-XXXXXX"
$resourceGroupName= "test"
$location = "East US"
$diskName="myDiskName"
$diskSize="1"
$vhdUri="https://strxxx.blob.core.windows.net/container/abcd .vhd"
$storageType="Standard_LRS"
az account set --subscription $subscriptionId
az disk create --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $diskName --sku $storageType --location $location --size-gb $diskSize --source $vhdUri
```

[***Output***](https://i.imgur.com/9wtDAsU.png):

```
 az disk create --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $diskName --sku $storageType --location $location --size-gb $diskSize --source $vhdUri
{
  "burstingEnabled": null,
  "burstingEnabledTime": null,
  "completionPercent": null,
  "creationData": {
    "createOption": "Import",
    "galleryImageReference": null,
    "imageReference": null,
    "logicalSectorSize": null,
    "performancePlus": null,
    "securityDataUri": null,
    "sourceResourceId": null,
    "sourceUniqueId": null,
    "sourceUri": "https://strfd1.blob.core.windows.net/container/abcd .vhd",
    "storageAccountId": "/subscriptions/7195d375-7af2-43f1-bd66-12e77ac05818/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Stor
age/storageAccounts/strfd1",
    "uploadSizeBytes": null
  },
```

In portal:

[image]

Now, create a virtual machine using an existing managed OS disk using CLI.

```
#Provide the subscription Id
$subscriptionId= "7195d375-7af2-43f1-bd66-xxxxx"
#Provide the name of your resource group
$resourceGroupName= "test"
#Provide the name of the Managed Disk
$managedDiskName= "myDiskName"
#Provide the OS type
$osType= "linux"
#Provide the name of the virtual machine
$virtualMachineName= "myVirtualMachineName123"
#Set the context to the subscription Id where Managed Disk exists and where VM will be created
az account set --subscription $subscriptionId
#Get the resource Id of the managed disk
$managedDiskId= "/subscriptions/7195d375-7af2-43f1-bd66-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/myDiskName"
$managedDiskId=$(az disk show --name $managedDiskName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --query [id] -o tsv)
#Create VM by attaching existing managed disks as OS
az vm create --name $virtualMachineName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --attach-os-disk $managedDiskId --os-type $osType
```

[**Output**](https://i.imgur.com/wQeKs10.png)

In portal:

[image]

***Managed disk:***

- A sort of virtual hard disk (VHD) is a managed disk, when you develop a virtual machine with managed disk, Azure automatically creates and manages the disk for you.
- Managed disks are persistent and can be detached from a VM and reattached to another VM. Azure manages managed disk, which offer better scalability and dependability.

***Ephemeral OS disks:***

- Ephemeral OS disks are temporary disks that are created and attached to a VM at runtime. Ephemeral OS disk are stored on the local disk of the virtual machine host, but they are not persistent when the VM is deallocated or stopped.
- When the VM is deallocated or stopped ephemeral OS disks are temporary and are deleted. Ephemeral OS disk is frequently used for stateless workloads that don't need persistent storage.

In general, managed disks should be used whenever virtual machine requires persistent storage.

***Reference***:

[Create a VM by attaching a managed disk as OS disk - CLI Sample - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/create-vm-from-managed-os-disks)